# Is handling concurrency in cron jobs important?

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a cron job in my application which does the following:

1. It gets entries from a database table whose status is set to 'pending'. Columns list is as below: id,name,title,ip,status
2. For each such entry it does a REST (Web service) call, get response, process it and store the data in database.

I presently set the cron job interval to 1 min.
But sometimes, it's execution might take as much as 5-10 mins (rare cases).

For my case, is it important to handle concurrency of cron job? Using lock files etc?

Presently when a entry is being processed, i'm change the value of the entries state column to 'processing', so that it is not processed again by the next call of cron job.

Comment: Unless there's a chance that the second job could start before the first one has set all the statuses to 'processing', I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lock files has extra advantage that if same script is executed twice (by mistake), only 
the first one will be executed.

Though you are setting column status 'pending', but I think it will still be problematic if script executed twice (at same time), unless you locked the rows/table.

Comment: if locks are used, if it takes more than avg time to processs a few rows, others have to wait for long right?